# Submitting forms without server side scripts

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I would like to be able to submit forms without server side scripts. Is this possible? I want it to be like prompt, where the user's input is stored in a variable. Is there a way to make it so whenever the user clicks the submit button, whatever they entered in the form is saved in a variable? Thanks!

Comment: It can be stored in a [**cookie**](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) or in [**local storage**](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp), but it means that this data will only be avaible on the user computer, not in the server.

Comment: store all inputs in one variable? what would you do with this variable then?

Comment: question is far too broad without better understanding of use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **local storage**. But the data will only be avaible on the user computer, not in the server.

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="box" id="box" value="" size="40" />
<button onclick="record()">record</button>
<button onclick="read()">read</button>
<span id=result></span>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function record () {
var content = document.getElementById('box').value;
localStorage.setItem("localdata", content);
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "stored!";
}

function read () {
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("localdata");
}
```

[**example on Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGYeaQ)

Comment: Notice the data remains stored even after reload the browser, until the user cleans up its cache.